# Correlations between numerous variables grouped in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

Say I have a data frame, like this:

```
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(33550336)

# Create dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(PC1 = runif(20),
                 PC2 = runif(20),
                 PC3 = runif(20),
                 A = runif(20),
                 B = runif(20),
                 loc = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = TRUE),
                 seas = sample(c("W", "S"), 20, replace = TRUE))

# > head(df)
#         PC1        PC2       PC3         A         B loc seas
# 1 0.8636470 0.02220823 0.7553348 0.4679607 0.0787467   A    S
# 2 0.3522257 0.42733152 0.2412971 0.6691419 0.1194121   A    W
# 3 0.5257408 0.44293320 0.3225228 0.0934192 0.2966507   B    S
# 4 0.0667227 0.90273594 0.6297959 0.1962124 0.4894373   A    W
# 5 0.3751383 0.50477920 0.6567203 0.4510632 0.4742191   B    S
# 6 0.9197086 0.32024904 0.8382138 0.9907894 0.9335657   A    S
```

I'm interested in calculating correlations between `PC1`, `PC2`, and `PC3` and each of the variables `A` and `B` grouped by `loc` and `seas`. So, for example, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51731607/1552004), I could do the following:

```
# Correlation of variable A and PC1 per loc & seas combination
df %>% 
  group_by(loc, seas) %>% 
  summarise(cor = cor(PC1, A)) %>% 
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   loc   seas      cor
#   <fct> <fct>   <dbl>
# 1 A     S      0.458 
# 2 A     W      0.748 
# 3 B     S     -0.0178
# 4 B     W     -0.450
```

This gives me what I want: the correlation between `PC1` and `A` for each combination of `loc` and `seas`. *Awesome*.

What I'm struggling with is extrapolating this to perform the calculation for each combination of `PC*` variables and other variables (i.e., `A` and `B`, in the example). My expected outcome is the tibble immediately above, but with a column for each combination for `PC*` and the other variables. I could do this long hand... `cor(PC2, A)`, `cor(PC3, A)`, `cor(PC1, B)`, etc., but presumably there is there a succinct way of coding the calculation. I suspect it involves `do`, but I can't quite get my head around it... Can someone enlighten me?

---

### Solution

I went with G. Grothendieck's [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764977/1552004), but this required some restructuring to get it into the required format. I have posted the code I used here in case it is useful for others.

```
# Perform calculation
res <- by(df[1:5], df[-(1:5)], cor)

# Combinations of loc & seas 
comb <- expand.grid(dimnames(res))

#   loc seas
# 1   A    S
# 2   B    S
# 3   A    W
# 4   B    W

# A matrix corresponding to a loc & seas
# Plus the loc & seas themselves
restructure <- function(m, n){
  # Convert to data frame
  # Add rownames as column
  # Retains PCs as rows, but not columns
  # Gather variables to long format
  # Unite PC & variable names
  # Spread to a single row
  # Add combination of loc & seas
  m %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>% 
    filter(grepl("PC", rownames(m))) %>% 
    select(-contains("PC")) %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -rowname) %>% 
    unite(comb, rowname, variable) %>% 
    spread(comb, value) %>% 
    bind_cols(n)
}

# Restructure each list element & combine into data frame
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(res), function(x)restructure(res[[x]], comb[x, ])))
```

which gives,

```
#         PC1_A       PC1_B      PC2_A       PC2_B      PC3_A     PC3_B loc seas
# 1  0.45763159 -0.00925106  0.3522161  0.20916667 -0.2003091 0.3741403   A    S
# 2 -0.01779813 -0.74328144 -0.3501188  0.46324158  0.8034240 0.4580262   B    S
# 3  0.74835455  0.49639477 -0.3994917 -0.05233889 -0.5902400 0.3606690   A    W
# 4 -0.45025181 -0.66721038 -0.9899521 -0.80989058  0.7606430 0.3738706   B    W
```

Comment: I m not sure but those seem to be eigenvectors :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `by` like this:

```
By <- by(df[1:5], df[-(1:5)], cor)
```

giving:

```
> By
loc: A
seas: S
            PC1        PC2        PC3          A           B
PC1  1.00000000 -0.3941583  0.1872622  0.4576316 -0.00925106
PC2 -0.39415826  1.0000000 -0.6797708  0.3522161  0.20916667
PC3  0.18726218 -0.6797708  1.0000000 -0.2003091  0.37414025
A    0.45763159  0.3522161 -0.2003091  1.0000000  0.57292305
B   -0.00925106  0.2091667  0.3741403  0.5729230  1.00000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
loc: B
seas: S
            PC1         PC2         PC3           A          B
PC1  1.00000000 -0.52651449  0.07120701 -0.01779813 -0.7432814
PC2 -0.52651449  1.00000000 -0.05448583 -0.35011878  0.4632416
PC3  0.07120701 -0.05448583  1.00000000  0.80342399  0.4580262
A   -0.01779813 -0.35011878  0.80342399  1.00000000  0.5558740
B   -0.74328144  0.46324158  0.45802622  0.55587404  1.0000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
loc: A
seas: W
           PC1         PC2        PC3          A           B
PC1  1.0000000 -0.79784422  0.0932317  0.7483545  0.49639477
PC2 -0.7978442  1.00000000 -0.3526315 -0.3994917 -0.05233889
PC3  0.0932317 -0.35263151  1.0000000 -0.5902400  0.36066898
A    0.7483545 -0.39949171 -0.5902400  1.0000000  0.18081316
B    0.4963948 -0.05233889  0.3606690  0.1808132  1.00000000
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
loc: B
seas: W
           PC1        PC2        PC3          A          B
PC1  1.0000000  0.3441459  0.1135686 -0.4502518 -0.6672104
PC2  0.3441459  1.0000000 -0.8447551 -0.9899521 -0.8098906
PC3  0.1135686 -0.8447551  1.0000000  0.7606430  0.3738706
A   -0.4502518 -0.9899521  0.7606430  1.0000000  0.8832408
B   -0.6672104 -0.8098906  0.3738706  0.8832408  1.0000000
```

### ADDED

Based on further discussion by poster on what is wanted define the `onerow` function which accepts a correlation matrix or a data frame (in the latter case it converts the first 5 columns to a correlatoin matrix) producing one row of the output.  The `if` statement in `onerow` is not needed, but won't hurt, for the `adply` line of code but we have included it so that `onerow` also works in a simple manner in subsequent examples below as well.

```
library(plyr)

onerow <- function(x) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) x <- cor(x[1:5])
  dtab <- as.data.frame.table(x[4:5, 1:3])
  with(dtab, setNames(Freq, paste(Var2, Var1, sep = "_")))
}

adply(By, 1:2, onerow)
```

giving:

```
  loc seas       PC1_A       PC1_B      PC2_A       PC2_B      PC3_A     PC3_B
1   A    S  0.45763159 -0.00925106  0.3522161  0.20916667 -0.2003091 0.3741403
2   B    S -0.01779813 -0.74328144 -0.3501188  0.46324158  0.8034240 0.4580262
3   A    W  0.74835455  0.49639477 -0.3994917 -0.05233889 -0.5902400 0.3606690
4   B    W -0.45025181 -0.66721038 -0.9899521 -0.80989058  0.7606430 0.3738706
```

or perhaps get rid of `by` altogether and use this giving the same output:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, -(1:5), onerow)
```

or using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by_at(-(1:5)) %>%
  do( onerow(.) %>% t %>% as.data.frame ) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with this solution, but have added the code used to restructure these results into the required format to the question.

Answer (score 4):

We can do a `split` and `cor` in `base R`

```
lapply(split(df[1:5], df[-(1:5)]), cor)
#$A.S
#            PC1        PC2        PC3          A           B
#PC1  1.00000000 -0.3941583  0.1872622  0.4576316 -0.00925106
#PC2 -0.39415826  1.0000000 -0.6797708  0.3522161  0.20916667
#PC3  0.18726218 -0.6797708  1.0000000 -0.2003091  0.37414025
#A    0.45763159  0.3522161 -0.2003091  1.0000000  0.57292305
#B   -0.00925106  0.2091667  0.3741403  0.5729230  1.00000000

#$B.S
#            PC1         PC2         PC3           A          B
#PC1  1.00000000 -0.52651449  0.07120701 -0.01779813 -0.7432814
#PC2 -0.52651449  1.00000000 -0.05448583 -0.35011878  0.4632416
#PC3  0.07120701 -0.05448583  1.00000000  0.80342399  0.4580262
#A   -0.01779813 -0.35011878  0.80342399  1.00000000  0.5558740
#B   -0.74328144  0.46324158  0.45802622  0.55587404  1.0000000

#$A.W
#           PC1         PC2        PC3          A           B
#PC1  1.0000000 -0.79784422  0.0932317  0.7483545  0.49639477
#PC2 -0.7978442  1.00000000 -0.3526315 -0.3994917 -0.05233889
#PC3  0.0932317 -0.35263151  1.0000000 -0.5902400  0.36066898
#A    0.7483545 -0.39949171 -0.5902400  1.0000000  0.18081316
#B    0.4963948 -0.05233889  0.3606690  0.1808132  1.00000000

#$B.W
#           PC1        PC2        PC3          A          B
#PC1  1.0000000  0.3441459  0.1135686 -0.4502518 -0.6672104
#PC2  0.3441459  1.0000000 -0.8447551 -0.9899521 -0.8098906
#PC3  0.1135686 -0.8447551  1.0000000  0.7606430  0.3738706
#A   -0.4502518 -0.9899521  0.7606430  1.0000000  0.8832408
#B   -0.6672104 -0.8098906  0.3738706  0.8832408  1.0000000
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by_at(6:7) %>% 
    nest %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, cor))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution via `tidyverse` where we use `summarise_at` to specify all `PC[0-9]` and correlate them with `A`. Same procedure for `B`, and then simply merge, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(loc, seas) %>% 
 summarise_at(vars(starts_with('PC')), funs(cor(., A))) %>% 
 left_join(., df %>% 
                 group_by(loc, seas) %>% 
                 summarise_at(vars(starts_with('PC')), funs(cor(., B))), 
          by = c('loc', 'seas'), suffix = c('.A', '.B'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 8
> # Groups:   loc [?]
>   loc   seas    PC1.A  PC2.A  PC3.A    PC1.B   PC2.B PC3.B
>   <fct> <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 A     S      0.458   0.352 -0.200 -0.00925  0.209  0.374
> 2 A     W      0.748  -0.399 -0.590  0.496   -0.0523 0.361
> 3 B     S     -0.0178 -0.350  0.803 -0.743    0.463  0.458
> 4 B     W     -0.450  -0.990  0.761 -0.667   -0.810  0.374
> ```

Comment: I like this solution because it gives the result in the required format, but can it be generalised to an arbitrary number of variables without having to add another `left_join...` line for each?

Comment: It can. We will have to loop over the columns `A`, `B`, ... I can give it a shot tomorrow.