# Weighted correlation using cov.wt and data.table by group

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, weighted

I have a `data.table` like this one:

```
set.seed(12345)
mydt <- data.table(gr1 = sample(letters[1:2], size = 100, replace = TRUE),
        gr2 = sample(letters[3:4], size = 100, replace = TRUE),
        a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), weight = rnorm(100, 5, 1))
```

The `gr1` and `gr2` specify the group membership of each case. I would like to obtain the correlation matrix from the `cov.wt` function by the group membership specified by `gr1` and `gr2`, using the `weight` column. The `cov.wt` returns the correlation matrix if `cor = TRUE`. I can split `mydt` by `gr1` and `gr2` and then use `lapply` to do the computations and extract each of the correlation matrices:

```
mydt <- split(x = mydt, by = c("gr1", "gr2"), drop = TRUE)

lapply(X = mydt, FUN = function(i) {
  cov.wt(x = as.matrix(i[ , c("a", "b")]), wt = i[ , weight], cor = TRUE)[["cor"]]
})
```

I get exactly what I want:

```
$b.c
                    a                   b
a 0.99999999999999978 0.26861150206539375
b 0.26861150206539375 0.99999999999999978

$a.c
                     a                    b
a  0.99999999999999978 -0.13281683546112405
b -0.13281683546112405  1.00000000000000000

$b.d
                     a                    b
a  1.00000000000000000 -0.13064774898011455
b -0.13064774898011455  1.00000000000000000

$a.d
                     a                    b
a  0.99999999999999978 -0.61122086293705469
b -0.61122086293705458  0.99999999999999978
```

However, with large datasets this approach is rather slow. I would like to use the `data.table` way to achieve this, just like the post from Dan Y [under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731493/how-to-calculate-correlation-by-group). I am struggling, thou, because of the extra parameters and the extraction of the correlation matrix from the list returned by the `cov.wt` function. I tried the following (plus many variations):

```
mydt[ , .(cov.wt(as.matrix(a, b), wt = weight, cor = TRUE)["cor"]), by = c("gr1", "gr2")]
```

What I get at the end is just the first value of the diagonal of each matrix.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the `as.matrix` is wrong because the 'x' is a single element and not multiple (based on the `?as.matrix`).  One option is to convert to matrix by `cbind`ing the vectors 'a', 'b', then wrap the output in a list (with `.()`)

```
library(data.table)
out <- mydt[ , .(.(cov.wt(cbind(a,b), wt = weight, cor = TRUE)["cor"])), 
    by = c("gr1", "gr2")]
out$V1
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$cor
#          a         b
#a 1.0000000 0.2686115
#b 0.2686115 1.0000000


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$cor
#           a          b
#a  1.0000000 -0.1328168
#b -0.1328168  1.0000000


#[[3]]
#[[3]]$cor
#           a          b
#a  1.0000000 -0.1306477
#b -0.1306477  1.0000000


#[[4]]
#[[4]]$cor
#           a          b
#a  1.0000000 -0.6112209
#b -0.6112209  1.0000000
```

NOTE: There is a difference in values due to the seed

Comment: Oh, God, you are so fast! Thank you very much, this solves the problem. Thank you for the explanation too.

Comment: Sorry, I have an additional question. I can pass wt as a character string (i.e. `get("weight")`, but how to pass a and b as a character string (i.e. `my.cols <- c("a", "b"))` to `cbind`, something like `cbind(my.cols)`. I tried different things, but it gives me an error "'x' must contain finite values only".

Comment: I got it:
my.cols <- c("a", "b")
my.keys <- c("gr1", "gr2")
out <- mydt[ , .(.(cov.wt(as.matrix(.SD), wt = get("weight"), cor = TRUE)["cor"])), by = my.keys, .SDcols = my.cols]
out[["V1"]]

Comment: Thank you! Works even faster than the solution I found and is more simple.